# Firefox canvas drawImage throws IndexSizeError

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas, drawimage

When I call the drawImage() function on a canvas 2d context object in Firefox, it throws the IndexSizeError, saying "Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount". From what I've read, this is supposed to happen when specifying a source rectangle that is not contained within the boundaries of the source image. This doesn't make sense, though, because the call I'm making is:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById(...)
var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
...
context.drawImage(this.image, this.data.x, this.data.y, this.data.w, this.data.h,
                  x - this.data.axRel * w * this.sx, y - this.data.ayRel * h * this.sy,
                  w * this.sx, h * this.sy)
```

and those parameters evaluate to:

```
<<a canvas object>>, 2, 2, 512, 512, -3.385562666666668, -6.540000000000001, 10.24, 10.24
```

The source bounds are `x=2, y=2, width=512, height=512` and the dimensions of the source image/canvas are 516x678. The region I'm picking fits.

This exception is only thrown sometimes - I have to close Firefox, reopen it, navigate to my webpage, and then reload the page in order to reproduce the exception - but the above parameters and the boundaries are printed immediately before and after the exception is thrown and the numbers are exactly what I expect and the same every time.

Comment: can you show your actual code please? If the error is on drawImage, we'd very much like to see the code involved with calling that

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I edited that into the original question, though I doubt there's an error there because the call works the vast majority of the time - it only fails in this one situation which is enough to make my entire app crash and require a page reload.

Comment: if that's where you error occurs, that's where the error is, and that makes the code important to show. Please also show what the canvas properties are for the one you're passing into `drawImage` as if it's an image. What's its width/height for instance?

Comment: That's the one I'm calling the source image. It's 516x678. The source rectangle fits.

Comment: can you debug that by using `var newimg = new Image(); newimg.src = this.image.toDataURL("image/png"); document.body.appendChild(newimg);` to see if that assumption is properly true? Does it show the intended image or is unexpected? (do you have a jsfiddle/jsbin that we can look at?)